# Supervisor remain the state when workers restart

Tags: elixir

I have a `AgentTest` as a worker for keep state, and a `Supv` as a Supervisor for monitor `AgentTest`

```
 defmodule AgentTest do
  use Agent

  def start_link(state) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> state end, name: :test) 
  end

  def incr do
    Agent.get_and_update(:test, fn state -> {state, state + 1} end) 
  end

  def crash do
    Agent.stop(:test, :crash) 
  end

  def get do
    Agent.get(:test, fn state -> state end) 
  end
end

defmodule Supv do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(Supv, []) 
  end

  def init(_arg) do
    Supervisor.init([
      {AgentTest, 1} 
    ], strategy: :one_for_one) 
  end
end
```

I tried in `iex`, the state is not remain when restart:

```
iex(2)> Supv.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.99.0>}
iex(3)> AgentTest.incr
1
iex(4)> AgentTest.incr
2
iex(5)> AgentTest.get
3
iex(6)> AgentTest.get
3
iex(7)> AgentTest.crash
:ok
iex(8)>
10:03:26.560 [error] GenServer :test terminating
** (stop) :crash
Last message: []
State: 3

nil
iex(9)> AgentTest.get
1
```

How to remain the `AgentTest` state when it restart by `Supv`?

I am using Elixir 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preserving a state, you can run a separate process, which will store a stash value.

```
defmodule Supv do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    children = [
      worker(Stash, [1]),
      worker(AgentTest, [])
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(Supv, children)
  end

  def init(children) do
    supervise children, strategy: :one_for_one
  end
end
```

When the main `AgentTest` process is terminated, it puts its current value into the stash. And when the process is restarted, it gets the value from the stash:

```
defmodule AgentTest do
  use Agent

  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> Stash.get() end, name: :test)
  end

  def incr do
    Agent.get_and_update(:test, fn state -> {state, state + 1} end)
  end

  def crash do
    Stash.update(get())

    Agent.stop(:test, :crash)
  end

  def get do
    Agent.get(:test, fn state -> state end)
  end
end
```

The stash process can be a simple `Agent`:

```
defmodule Stash do
  use Agent

  def start_link(initial_number) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> initial_number end, name: :stash)
  end

  def get do
    Agent.get(:stash, fn state -> state end)
  end

  def update(number) do
    Agent.update(:stash, fn _ -> number end)
  end
end
```

To simplify the example, I named the process (`:stash`), but its `pid` can certainly be passed as an argument to `AgentTest`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if `Stash` crash too? so create a another `Stash2` for this problem? But if `Stash2` crashed?  that will be a infinite circle.  I am new to Elixir/Erlang, I wanna to know that is it necessary for preserving all processes states?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to preserve the value of the `Stash`. The value is valuable until `AgentTest` is restarted, just to write the new current value into `AgentTest`. So, you don't need `Stash2`, etc...

Comment: @TangMonk Then perhaps you might want to save this state on disk, and load it at startup ;) or "just" use a separate database.

Comment: @Uniaika thanks, I got it, state preserve is not necessary for every solutions, short live connection(http) is do not necessary for state preserve, but long live connection(websocket) is necessary. I am misunderstand of 'Let it Crash'.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `:ets`. For each update you can store this info also in ets and get this value at the start of `start_link`.